# How can use bash command command in docker-compose volume?

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file for running `Postgresql`:

It seems `docker-compose` couldn't understand the `pwd` bash command

```
version: '3.4'

networks:
  network-set: null

volumes:
  postgres-data: null

services:
  postgres:
    restart: always
    networks:
      - network-set
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - $(pwd)/command/init.sh:docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 4.2.2.4
    env_file:
      - env/postgres.env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

**Error:**

```
WARNING: The pwd variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
```

**Question:**

How can solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.` instead

```
volumes:
  - ./command/init.sh:docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

This is always [interpreted](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#short-syntax-3) as relative to the location of the `docker-compose.yml` file, if you're running the `docker-compose` command from some other directory.

Docker Compose doesn't allow command substitutions or most other shell features anywhere at all, except for the basic forms of [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).